# Send value from child component back to parent component while using switch-case

Tags: reactjs

PROBLEM: When I click between each button in my child `Sidebar` component, the function that I passed down to switch pages between ***archived*** and ***profile*** doesn't  send back the value of `state` or (the page) to my `Dashboard` component's `RenderComponent` switch statement; which, in turn, doesn't render the proper components in my parent `Dashboard` component.

My parent component `Dashboard` has the following code:

```js
const [param, setParam] = useState("created");

  const RenderComponent = (param) => {
    switch (param) {
      case "created":
        return (
          <>
            <AddButton />
            <PortfolioList />
          </>
        );
      case "archived":
        return <Archived />;
      default:
        return "foo";
    }
  };
   
  // use function in Sidebar component
  const changeParam = (e) => {
    setParam(e);
  };
```

And here is the component that renders on the webpage in my `Dashboard` component:

```js
<>
 <Left>
    <SideBar changeParam={changeParam} />
</Left>
<Middle>{RenderComponent(param)}</Middle>
</>
```

Then, I'm passing my `changeParam` function to  my  `Sidebar`  component as a prop:

```js
function SideBar({ changeParam }) {
  const [state, setState] = useState("created");

  const handlePage = (page) => {
    setState(page);
    // using the function passed from parent component
    changeParam(page);
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      
        <Button
          onClick={() => handlePage("archived")}
        >
        </Button>

        <Button
          onClick={() => handlePage("profile")}
        >
        </Button>
     
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Any ideas how to make this  work?

Answer (score 0):

Change `changeParam(state)` into `changeParam(page)`: state updates [are not immediate](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous).

Comment: Changed this, but now my whole app freezes

Comment: In a fresh project your code does work as expected with this minor update, so the issue is elsewhere. In any case, both of the problems probably stem from the fact that you are not [lifting the state up](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) properly. There should ideally be only one state in the parent component, not two separate states in both the parent and the child.